# Logging exception error upgrading to python 3.4 from python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, python-3.4, error-logging

My application was running well but as I upgraded it to python version 3.4 . I am getting the error shown bellow. Looking at the error message I am not exactly able to debug the problem

**Error:**

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 978, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 828, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 573, in format
    record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 523, in formatException
    traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], tb, None, sio)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/traceback.py", line 169, in print_exception
    for line in _format_exception_iter(etype, value, tb, limit, chain):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/traceback.py", line 146, in _format_exception_iter
    for value, tb in values:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/traceback.py", line 125, in _iter_chain
    context = exc.__context__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__context__'
Call stack:
  File "main.py", line 253, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 144, in main
    plugininfo.plugin_object.run(cons.MAIN_CONFIG_PATH, outputpath, finallogs, plugininfo.name, args.inventory)
  File "/home/sjoshi/python3.4/check-acess/plugins/plugin_etc_passwd/plugin_etc_passwd.py", line 107, in run
    self.result = phelper.executeCommand(runcommand)
  File "/home/sjoshi/python3.4/check-acess/lib/sshplugin/sshplugin.py", line 86, in executeCommand
    logging.exception("ErrorCode:%d %s", cmdout.returncode, output)
Message: 'ErrorCode:%d %s'
Arguments: (255, b'')
No Result found or all users filtered sbx32 /etc/passwd
Permission denied (publickey).
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 978, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 828, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 573, in format
    record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 523, in formatException
    traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], tb, None, sio)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/traceback.py", line 169, in print_exception
    for line in _format_exception_iter(etype, value, tb, limit, chain):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/traceback.py", line 146, in _format_exception_iter
    for value, tb in values:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/traceback.py", line 125, in _iter_chain
    context = exc.__context__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__context__'
Call stack:
  File "main.py", line 253, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 144, in main
    plugininfo.plugin_object.run(cons.MAIN_CONFIG_PATH, outputpath, finallogs, plugininfo.name, args.inventory)
  File "/home/sjoshi/python3.4/check-acess/plugins/plugin_etc_passwd/plugin_etc_passwd.py", line 107, in run
    self.result = phelper.executeCommand(runcommand)
  File "/home/sjoshi/python3.4/check-acess/lib/sshplugin/sshplugin.py", line 86, in executeCommand
    logging.exception("ErrorCode:%d %s", cmdout.returncode, output)
Message: 'ErrorCode:%d %s'
Arguments: (255, b'')
```

**sshplugin.py**

```
import os
import subprocess as subp
import logging
import lib.exceptions.errors as error
import lib.inventory.bashhostlist as hostname

class SSHPlugin:
    """
    Helper class for the SSH based plugins

    """

    def makeCommand(self, user, host, filepath, sudo, timeout, attempt, changetols=None):
        """ 
        -Two types of commands with or without ssh depends on hostname
        -Other depends on parameter set or unset
        -ConnectionAttempts and ConnectTimeout to occur must be SSH

        -last arg(changetols): This is to checkif the plugin type is authorized_keys. Because in that case we need ls not cat
        """
        command=""
        if changetols is None:
            command = ["cat", filepath]
        else:
            command=["ls", filepath]

        if host.lower() == 'localhost':
            if sudo.lower() == 'yes':
                command.insert(0, 'sudo')

        else:
            command.insert(0, "ssh")
            if timeout and not attempt:
                command.insert(1, '-o')
                command.insert(
                    2, "ConnectTimeout={timeout}".format(timeout=timeout))
                command.insert(3, user+"@"+host)
                if sudo.lower() == 'yes':
                    command.insert(4, 'sudo')
            elif timeout and attempt:
                command.insert(1, '-o')
                command.insert(
                    2, "ConnectTimeout={timeout}".format(timeout=timeout))
                command.insert(3, '-o')
                command.insert(
                    4, "ConnectionAttempts={att}".format(att=attempt))
                command.insert(5, user+"@"+host)
                if sudo.lower() == 'yes':
                    command.insert(6, 'sudo')
            elif attempt and not timeout:
                command.insert(1, '-o')
                command.insert(
                    2, "ConnectionAttempts={att}".format(att=attempt))
                command.insert(3, user+"@"+host)
                if sudo.lower() == 'yes':
                    command.insert(4, 'sudo')
            else:
                command.insert(1, user+"@"+host)
                if sudo.lower() == 'yes':
                    command.insert(2, 'sudo')


        return command

    def executeCommand(self, command, filtercommand=None):
        """
        Multuple Popen used to execute the process,Command followed by filter if any

        if no filter than just a single commad run else
        The output of first will act as the input to the filtering command 

        """

        if filtercommand is None:
            cmdout = subp.Popen(command, stdout=subp.PIPE)
            output, err = cmdout.communicate()
            if cmdout.returncode is 0:
                logging.info("Result success,status code %d", cmdout.returncode)
                return output
            else:
                logging.exception("ErrorCode:%d %s %s", cmdout.returncode, output,err)
                return False
        else:
            cmdout = subp.Popen(command, stdout=subp.PIPE)
            filtered = subp.Popen(filtercommand, stdin=cmdout.stdout, stdout=subp.PIPE)
            output, err = filtered.communicate()
            if filtered.returncode is 0:
                logging.info("Result success,status code %d", filtered.returncode)
                return output
            else:
                logging.exception("ErrorCode:%d %s", filtered.returncode, output)
                return False
```

why is the logging.exception throwing errors. Is it the problem with the logging module. I tried to replace the logging.exception with logging.info instead  but that didn't work.

Comment: do you have a [mcve] ?

Comment: [`Logger.exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) *"should only be called from an exception handler"*, i.e. inside an `except` block.

Comment: that is the exception method of logging library not exactly a exceptional handler. i may replace that with `info` method or `error` than that should have worked at least  right .for example `logging.info()`

Comment: I removed my answer since it was wrong, sorry! I tested with `python3.6` that handles the error of missing exception context, which is not the case in `python3.4` obviously.